# how NOT to restore deleted files and folders with CrashPlan?

Tags: restore, crashplan

I want to use our corporate CrashPlan backup in order to transfer files from my current (backed up) laptop to the replacement one. This just seems easier and more correct procedure than attaching an external drive and copying tens of gigs of data. The new laptop has the CP installed and sees my backup, so this should not be a problem. Except, I cleaned up the old computer before the procedure, freeing many gigs of space. The removed folders are still showing up in CP, that's ok. But I don't see how to indicate in Restore not to take them?

I know I'm looking at a non-standard use of the backup software, but if a computer crashes and a replacement is prepared, it seems a basic requirement to restore the most recent state. Unless, a "restore most recent versions" implies that deleted files are not restored.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Uncheck show deleted files
 Check only the files/folders you want to restore.
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but that's the thing - I don't want to go over the whole tree and try to remember what is active and what's deleted; I want to restore the entire disk in one command. Seems pretty basic to me. "show deleted files" is unchecked

Comment: If crashplan finished syncing the deleted list then unchecking **show deleted files** should hide them.

Answer (score -1):

In case this helps another person in the same situation ...

If "verify file selection" has not run recently, then deleted files will not be flagged as deleted in the backup. Unfortunately this setting defaults to running every day at 3am. If your computer is asleep or off at 3am it will not run.

You do not receive any notification that the scan has not run.

I ran in to this restoring my computer and discovered that my computer had not run this "very important critical step" (as described by CrashPlan support) in 5 years. I restored hundreds of deleted files that had to be manually removed.

The solution is to set the scan interval to 23 hours, then it will attempt to run if at least 23 hours have elapsed since the last scan (this is the longest value allowed).

Hope this helps.